# Move an Elastic IP from a VPC to Classic EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-ip

I know it is possible to "Move to VPC Scope", but is it also possible to move back from VPC to Classic EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Classic EC2 goes away entirely in 11 days, and it hasn't been possible to create a classic version account since 2013.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html

> We are retiring EC2-Classic on August 15, 2022. We recommend that you migrate from EC2-Classic to a VPC.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-classic-is-retiring-heres-how-to-prepare/

> On August 15, 2022 we expect all migrations to be complete, with no remaining EC2-Classic resources present in any AWS account.

You can do anything you could do in classic within a VPC.